# OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Grant - Handling of Access Token Upon Logging Out

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I am new to OAuth 2.0. I used BShaffer's OAuth PHP Server on Authorization Code Grant, and I understand that the client application can have its OAuth token separate from its session authentication, that is, if a user logs out, the access token is not revoked, and when it expires, the refresh token is used to get a new access token.

I am building a trusted application using an API with OAuth User Credential (or Resource Owner) Grant. My questions are:

1. Since I am in OAuth User Credential Grant, should OAuth hold all the user credentials and solely be the user authentication layer (which would act like an SSO layer)?
2. With that and the given grant type, should I use the OAuth token as a session token? Upon logging out of the client application, should I revoke the OAuth token?

Comment: Password grant: On logout simply delete the auth token on the client. And on login create a new token using the refresh token for that user.